# What does - means in kubectl -f -

Tags: kubectl, kustomize

What does the last - (following `-f`) mean in the following command:

`kustomize build config/samples | kubectl apply -f -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippet from [kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply):

**Apply the JSON passed into stdin to a pod**

> cat pod.json | kubectl apply -f -

Comment: Note that this convention of providing "-" as the file name, to represent stdin, is extremely common in Linux commands.